# SharePoint 2016 SPFx React TypeScript Issue

Tags: 2016, spfx, spfx-webparts, react, office-ui-fabric-react

I am getting an error of TypeScript 2.2.2 in SharePoint 2016.

I can install SPFx web part with No JavaScript Framework approach. And it's working fine but when I choose "React" in "yo @microsoft/sharepoint" command then I got below error.

Package JSON:

```
{
  "name": "fifth-wp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.1.0",
    "@types/es6-collections": "^0.5.31",
    "@types/react": "15.0.38",
    "@types/react-addons-shallow-compare": "0.14.17",
    "@types/react-addons-test-utils": "0.14.15",
    "@types/react-addons-update": "0.14.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "0.14.18",
    "@types/webpack-env": ">=1.12.1 <1.14.0",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.1.0",
    "@types/chai": ">=3.4.34 <3.6.0",
    "@types/mocha": ">=2.2.33 <2.6.0",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1"
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New:

My package .json :

```
{
  "name": "spfx",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.1.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": ">=1.12.1 <1.14.0",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2",
    "@types/react": "0.14.46",
    "@types/react-dom": "0.14.18",
    "@types/react-addons-shallow-compare": "0.14.17",
    "@types/react-addons-update": "0.14.14",
    "@types/react-addons-test-utils": "0.14.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.1.0",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "@types/chai": ">=3.4.34 <3.6.0",
    "@types/mocha": ">=2.2.33 <2.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  }
}
```

version of node is 6.10.3 and npm is 3.10.10 is working fine.

Ref Link: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2089